# Divide Grayscale Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a 1024x396 grayscale image.

What are the ways I can split this image equally  into 3 equal parts ?

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: there are 3 pictures in one image one below another, and I want to seperate them apart

Comment: You needed to be more specific regarding the sizes of these "sub-images" that are within one image. Are they equal parts or vary in sizes, orientation, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
img1 = img(1:341,:);
img2 = img(342:681,:);
img3 = img(682:1024,:);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
part1 = img(:,1:132);
part2 = img(:,133:264);
part3 = img(:,265:end);
```